# Showing 'This folder is empty' background when my shell extension folder is empty

Tags: winapi, explorer, shell-extensions, hresult, apimonitor

In my shell extension, I want to mimic explorer's behavior and show '*This folder is empty*' message when in fact my folder is empty:

[image: ThisFolderIsEmpty]

However, I can't accomplish it.

Using API Monitor, I see that when explorer refreshes an empty folder, `IEnumIDList::Next()` is returning the following:

[image: APIMonitorScreenshot]

Meaning, that the 'next' item returned is `NULL`, the number of items is `0` and the result is `S_FALSE`.

As mentioned, I tried to mimic the return values, and indeed no items are loaded for the folder, but no message appear either.

So what API would trigger this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IEnumIDList implementation must implement IObjectWithSite. Sample of implementation:

```
  var
    ServiceProvider: IServiceProvider;
    ShellBrowser: IShellBrowser;
    ShellView: IShellView;
    FolderView2: IFolderView2;
  begin
    if not Assigned(ASite) then Exit;
    OleCheck(ASite.QueryInterface(IServiceProvider, ServiceProvider));
    try
      OleCheck(ServiceProvider.QueryService(SID_STopLevelBrowser, IShellBrowser, ShellBrowser));
      try
        OleCheck(ShellBrowser.QueryActiveShellView(ShellView));
        try
          OleCheck(ShellView.QueryInterface(IFolderView2, FolderView2));
          try
            FolderView2.SetText(FVST_EMPTYTEXT, 'The message you want to see');
          finally
            FolderView2 := nil;
          end;
        finally
          ShellView := nil;
        end;
      finally
        ShellBrowser := nil;
      end;
    finally
      ServiceProvider := nil;
    end;
  end;
```

Result:

[image]

Also you can use the same code in your IShellFolder implementation.

Comment: I see that `IObjectWithSite` requires to implement `SetSite` and `GetSite`. What do I see in your example? Perhaps do you mean to implement `IFolderView2`? It is a pretty large interface

Comment: I used my implementation of `IFolderView2` and it worked great. Thank you! Please edit your answer so I could accept it

Comment: What you mean when you write "used my implementation of IFolderView2"? I don`t offer you to create full implementation of IFolderView2. I just offer you to set "Empty folder" message of windows default implementation of IFolderView2. If you want to use your own implementation of IFolderView2 for message only - it is overhead.

Comment: Yes, you are right, my implementation was practically using the default one without thinking it through. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

***This is an old question but I write my answer. It might be useful to someone***

**You can change the empty folder view text in `IShellFolder::CreateViewObject` method, like below:**

```
  if (riid == IID_IShellView)
  {
    m_hwndOwner = hwndOwner;

    SFV_CREATE sfvData = { sizeof sfvData };
    const CComQIPtr<IShellFolder> spFolder = GetUnknown();
    sfvData.psfvcb = this;
    sfvData.pshf = spFolder;

    auto hr = SHCreateShellFolderView(&sfvData, reinterpret_cast<IShellView**>(ppv));

    // Here we change the text
    auto pSV = *reinterpret_cast<IShellView**>(ppv);
    CComPtr<IFolderView2> pFV;
    pSV->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFV));
    pFV->SetText(FVST_EMPTYTEXT, L"Put your text here!");
    //-

    return hr;
  }
```